# The jquery dialogbox didn't close when it is opened on usercontrol page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I used the jQuery dialog. The parent has user control which has an image to open the popup page when it is on click. The aspx page has cancel button to close jquery method and it is worked. I added the my jquery files on the parent page. I put the dialog div on parent page.

The problem is for closing the jquery dialog box and reloading the parent. If I added my jquery files on the header on the popup page, the function is called but the error is:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'dialog'.  Also the Cancel button didn't close the jquery.

However, when I uncomment my jquery files on the popup page, the cancel button works. But the another button which close the popup and reload parent page, the jquery method is not called and the popup page reload and not closed.

There is my code in jQuery

```
function openmodel(url, name, width, height) {
  var maxHeight = dialogMaxHeight(height);
  var dialogHeight = height;
  if (height > maxHeight)
    dialogHeight = maxHeight;   

  $('#dialog-model').dialog({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    max_height:'auto',      
    height: 'auto',
    width: width,
    title: name,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,        
    open: function( ) { 
        $(this).load(url);           
    }, 
 });

$('#dialog-model').dialog('open');
return false;
}

function CloseDialogmodel() {    
    $('#dialog-model').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,     
        title: name,
        modal: true, 
    });

    $('#dialog-model').dialog('close');
 }


function CloseDialogModelAndReloadParent() {    
   CloseDialogmodel(); }
```

The code behind on aspx page:

```
 Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
 'do something on server
  Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType (), "closeandload", "CloseDialogBoxAndReloadParent();", True)
End Sub
```

Hope someone tell me how to resolve the problem, so I can close the popup page and reload it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean about `when I uncomment my jQuery files...`? Is it the file that includes the code above?. And if better, please provide the html to help us have a clearer look on your case.

Comment: I think you need to show more code. html would be useful.

Comment: @Kai, the file includes my jquery code.  If I put the lines <script language="javascript" src="/test/Myjdialog.js"></script><script language="javascript" src="/test/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> on popup page. the function is called but the error is: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'. Also the Cancel button didn't close the jquery.

Comment: you should edit your question and provide us your html structure.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and I handled it like below:

**Child.aspx-Markup**

```
<div class="button">   
    <asp:Button ID="btnDone" Text="Done" runat="server" />

    <a ID="lnkClose" onclick="DecideForParent(false,true);return false;">
        Close
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DecideForParent(AllowReferesh, AllowClose) {
        try {
            if (AllowReferesh)
                window.opener.HandlePopupResult();
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
        // Close dialog
        if (AllowClose)
            $('#dialog-model').dialog('close');
    }
</script>
```

**Child.aspx-Code behind (C#)**

```
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Do something ...
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallreturnToParent", "$(window).load(function () { DecideForParent(true,true);return false;});", true);
}
```

**Parent.aspx-Markup**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HandlePopupResultLURow() {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>').click();
    }
</script>
```

**Parent.aspx-Code behind (C#)**

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Refresh your data        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if i guess right, you create the dialog like this

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  //....
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Do Action": function() {
              CloseDialogBoxAndReloadParent();
    },
    "Cancel" : function() {
     CloseDialogBox();

    }
  }
});
```

} );

if you add the element to the parameters

```
 "Cancel" : function() {
     CloseDialogBox(this);

    }
```

you can access the right element

```
function CloseDialogBox(element) {
$(element).dialog('close');
```

}

Comment: I need to do something on code behind and close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CloseDialogmodel () {
    $('#dialog-model').dialog({ autoOpen: false, resizable: true, title: name, modal: true, });
    $('#dialog-model').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: If you want to add something to your answer, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) it instead of posting a comment on it. I've just edited your comment into the answer for you, so you can remove your comment now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it . I just need to respond redirect the parent page on btnDone_Click. Thanks.